# Using Testcontainers without Spring

Tags: java, docker, testing, junit, testcontainers

I started to understand Docker and Testcontainers for homework, where the use of Spring is forbidden. The project uses a database - there are different interactions with it. I have deployed the database in Docker, but I don't understand how to write tests through Testcontainers. For example, how to test adding data to the database, or changing data in the database, or just output from the database? I have connected the container in the test class via:

```
 private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15.2");
```

But what to do next? All the examples, youtube videos, etc use Spring... Thanks in advance!

*Below I present examples of functions*

**Add to DB function**

```
    @Override
    public void addTransaction(TypeOfTransaction type, int amount) {
        String sql = """
                INSERT INTO entities."Transaction" (type, amount)
                VALUES (?, ?)
                """;
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.open();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(type));
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, amount);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Update DB function**

```
    @Override
    public void minusBalance(String login, int amount) {
        String sql = """
                UPDATE entities."Client"
                SET balance = balance - ?
                WHERE login = ?
                """;
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.open();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, amount);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, login);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Print data from DB function**

```
    @Override
    public void printAudit(String login) {
        String sql = """
                SELECT action
                FROM "Client_Audit"
                WHERE client_login = ?
                """;
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.open();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, login);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("action"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I tried to find an example of using testcontainers without Spring on YouTube, in various articles, but no luck :(

Comment: Where does the `ConnectionManager` come from?  How is it configured?  You'd need to pass the IP address and port from the `PostgreSQLContainer<T>` into that.  (Also consider whether an in-memory database like H2 or HDBC will work: it will be much faster and simpler than Testcontainers and can run in more places.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read first [this article](https://testcontainers.com/guides/introducing-testcontainers/) in order to understand what Testcontainers does. Then, look at other [article](https://testcontainers.com/guides/getting-started-with-testcontainers-for-java/) which use `PostgreSQLContainer` without Spring.

In summary, Testcontainers will create and run the container in a random port, when using PostgreSQLContainer you can get the JDBC URL with `getJdbcUrl()` that should be used in `DriverManager.getConnection(postgres.getJdbcUrl(), postgres.getUsername(), postgres.getPassword());`